# AppRequest sent by my webapp is not received on the mobile Facebook website (in iOS)

Tags: ios, facebook, mobile-safari, apprequests, facebook-app-requests

- My app isn't declared in sandbox.
- I did specified a canvas URL for redirection.
- The notification (apprequest) works well when sent from my webapp to the **desktop facebook website.** It well appears on the desktop version.

However, I can't receive the notifications **from my Facebook mobile website**.
I use Safari on my Iphone 4S and iOS 7.X.

Might it be normal?
Is there any way to detect them in the Facebook mobile version ?
As many users only use smartphones those days, I think it would be important to manage the mobile version of Facebook to detect the apprequests.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add Website Platform and add Mobile Site URL

Settings > Add Platform > Website > then add ur Mobile Site URL

you also need to enable App Center Listed Platforms

App Details > App Center Listed Platforms > enable app on facebook and website - mobile

hope this helps